# Why does my script not run the if statement when I type 5?

Tags: batch-file

When I type 5 the batch file exits and does nothing. I am trying to run the script in the if statement. But only when you type 5. Now nothing happens so I am asking: Why does my script not run the if statement when I typ 5?

THNX

```
choice /c:12345 /n

if ERRORLEVEL 5 (
    set snelheid=f5
    goto tempsnelheid
)
if ERRORLEVEL 4 (
    set snelheid=f4
    goto tempsnelheid
)
if ERRORLEVEL 3 (
    set snelheid=f3
    goto tempsnelheid
)
if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    set snelheid=f2
    goto tempsnelheid
)
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    set snelheid=f1
    goto tempsnelheid
)

:tempsnelheid
if "snelheid"=="f5" (
    echo hoi
    pause
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are compairing the **string** "snelheid", not the value of the variable nammed sneilheid.

So

```
:tempsnelheid
if "snelheid"=="f5" (
    echo hoi
    pause
)
```

shoud be

```
:tempsnelheid
if %snelheid%=="f5" (
    echo hoi
    pause
)
```

Comment: OMG that I would do something like that! Im sleeping right now... thank you!

Comment: time to lunch maybe? ;)